# Use specialized implementation if a class instance is available

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Consider the following situation:

```
slow_func :: Eq a  => [a] -> [a]
fast_func :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

I have two functions, `slow_func` and `fast_func`. These functions are different implementations of the same abstract function (they do the same thing), but one is faster than the other. The faster implementation is only available if the type `a` can be ordered. Is there a way to construct a function which acts as `fast_func` when possible, and reverts to `slow_func` otherwise?

```
as_fast_as_possible_func :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

I have already tried the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances  #-}

class Func a where
    as_fast_as_possible_func :: [a] -> [a]

instance Ord a => Func a where
    as_fast_as_possible_func = fast_func

instance Eq a => Func a where
    as_fast_as_possible_func = slow_func
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile, generating the following error:

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
  instance Ord a => Func a
    -- Defined at [...]
  instance Eq a => Func a
    -- Defined at [...]
```

The reason is that `OverlappingInstances` wants one of the instances to be most specialized *with respect to the instance specification, ignoring its context* (rather than using the most restrictive context, which is what we need here).

Any way to do this?

Comment: I would say "no". It would break separate compiling, and/or introduce backtracking in the instance search algorithm. The latter would make compile time grow exponentially, in the worst case. Overlapping instances are already a bad enough idea (IMO).

Comment: Make the default definition `as_fast_as_possible_func = fast_func` and, if that fails (because the class is not an instance of `Eq`)  the implementer can define it as `slow_func` instead? Leave a comment saying that `slow_func` is available as the second option?

Comment: @Davislor wouldn't I still need two instance declarations, leading to the same problem? As far as I can tell the only thing that changes is that I can leave one instance declaration empty.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745038/ghc-rewrite-rule-specialising-a-function-for-a-type-class

Comment: These are untested kludges, but one idea: override `as_fast_as_possible_func` for individual types `a`, which is extra work but should at least meet the requirements of `OverlappingInstances`? Alternatively, `isOrd = True`, then use lazy evaluation (and possibly some type coercion) to run either `slow_func` or `fast_func` based on that? Seems like there ought to be a better way, so I might be misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: The way the class system was originally designed to be used is that you don't declare your two polymorphic instances, you make a separate concrete instance for each type. The whole type class machinery is designed so that decisions about which instance to choose **can't** be based on which other instances are in scope, in order to promote coherence (we don't want two modules importing your `Func` to choose different instances for the same type based on which other modules they've imported). I would probably just use `slow_func` and `fast_func` directly without trying to unify them.

Answer (score 10):

Turned out actually you can. Seriously, I'm starting to think that everything is possible in Haskell... You can use results of recently announced [`constraint-unions`](https://github.com/rampion/constraint-unions#readme) approach. I'm using code similar to one that was written by [@leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout). Not sure I did it in best way, just tried to apply concepts of proposed approach:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Wno-name-shadowing #-}

{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators              #-}

module Main where

import           Data.List (group, nub, sort)

infixr 2 ||
class  c || d where
    resolve :: (c => r) -> (d => r) -> r

slowFunc :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
slowFunc = nub

fastFunc :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
fastFunc = map head . group . sort

as_fast_as_possible_func :: forall a. (Ord a || Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
as_fast_as_possible_func = resolve @(Ord a) @(Eq a) fastFunc slowFunc

newtype SlowWrapper = Slow Int deriving (Show, Num, Eq)
newtype FastWrapper = Fast Int deriving (Show, Num, Eq, Ord)

instance      (Ord FastWrapper || d) where resolve = \r _ -> r
instance d => (Ord SlowWrapper || d) where resolve = \_ r -> r

main :: IO ()
main = print . sum . as_fast_as_possible_func $ (Fast . round) 
                                             <$> [sin x * n | x<-[0..n]]
  where n = 20000
```

The key part here is `as_fast_as_possible_func`:

```
as_fast_as_possible_func :: forall a. (Ord a || Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
as_fast_as_possible_func = resolve @(Ord a) @(Eq a) fastFunc slowFunc
```

It uses appropriate function depending on whether `a` is `Ord` or `Eq`. I put `Ord` on the first place because everything that is `Ord` is automatically `Eq` and type checker rules might not trigger (though I didn't tested this function with constraints swapped). If you use `Slow` here `(Fast . round)` instead of `Fast` you can observe significantly slower results:

```
$ time ./Nub  # With `Slow` 
Slow 166822

real    0m0.971s
user    0m0.960s
sys     0m0.008s


$ time ./Nub  # With `Fast` 
Fast 166822

real    0m0.038s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated required instances. Instead of

```
instance (c || Eq SlowWrapper)  where resolve = \_ r -> r
```

Now it is

```
instance d => (Ord SlowWrapper || d) where resolve = \_ r -> r
```

[Thanks @rampion for explanation!](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6k86je/constraint_unions_bringing_or_to_the_language_of/djklw8v/)

Comment: Since you have to manually wrap values, you might as well manually call the correct function.

Comment: He only wrapped the values, to get rid of `Ord` for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @LukaHorvat I used wrapped values only for demonstration purposes. You can use this approach w/o wrapper. It's just incredibly hard to find some standard data type which implements `Eq` but doesn't implement `Ord` to show that solution actually works.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I thought it was a general newtype like `FastWrapper a`. But my comment still stands. You'll need to write an instance for every possible type you want to use with your function at which point you might as well have a special class for them.

Comment: @LukaHorvat Yes, unfortunately, it's a downside of this `constraint-unions` approach — it requires some boilerplate code. Hopefully, instances are very easy to write. And you need to write them once per program for each type instead of manually wrapping values at call-site. Also, you can accidentally write `slowFunc` instead of `fastFunc` at call-site while with this approach you get correct behavior automatically.

Answer (score 9):

I would consider two options:

### Rewrite rules

You can nominally use `slow_func` everywhere, but let rewrite rules optimise it when possible. For example,

```
import Data.List

slowFunc :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
slowFunc = nub

fastFunc :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
fastFunc = map head . group . sort

main = print . sum . slowFunc $ round <$> [sin x * n | x<-[0..n]]
 where n = 100000
```

is slow (duh):

```
$ ghc -O2 Nub.hs && time ./Nub
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Nub.hs, Nub.o )
Linking Nub ...
-3670322

real    0m51.875s
user    0m51.867s
sys 0m0.004s
```

but if we add (without changing anything)

```
{-# NOINLINE slowFunc #-}
{-# RULES "slowFunc/Integer" slowFunc = fastFunc :: [Integer] -> [Integer] #-}
```

then

```
$ ghc -O2 Nub.hs && time ./Nub
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Nub.hs, Nub.o )
Linking Nub ...
-3670322

real    0m0.250s
user    0m0.245s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Rewrite rules are a bit hard to rely on (inlining is just one thing that can get in the way), but at least you can be sure that something that runs with `slowFunc` will keep *working* (just perhaps not fast enough) but definitely won't get lost in some missing-instance issue. On the flip side, you should also make very sure that `slowFunc` and `fastFunc` actually behave the same – in my example, this is not actually given! (But it can easily be modified accordingly).

As Alec emphasizes in the comments, you will need to add a rewrite rule *for every single type* that you want to make fast. The good thing is that this can be done after the code is finished and exactly where profiling indicates that it matters, performance-wise.

### Individual instances

This is the reliable solution: abstain from any catch-all instances and instead decide for each type what's appropriate.

```
instance Func Int where
    as_fast_as_possible_func = fast_func
instance Func Double where
    as_fast_as_possible_func = fast_func
...

instance Func (Complex Double) where
    as_fast_as_possible_func = slow_func
```

You can save some duplicate lines by making the more common version the default:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultInstances #-}

class Func a where
  as_fast_as_possible_func :: [a] -> [a]
  default as_fast_as_possible_func :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
  as_fast_as_possible_func = fast_func

instance Func Int
instance Func Double
...

instance Func (Complex Double) where
    as_fast_as_possible_func = slow_func
```

Comment: The rewrite rule approach is nice, but it is worth mentioning you still need to add one rule per specialized signature; there is no way to add a rewrite rule which optimizes `slowFunc = fastFunc` whenever the `Ord` constraint is satisfied. You still need to manually indicate types where this fact can be immediately witnessed by GHC.

Comment: I greatly dislike the rewrite rule approach. It's too easy to get awful performance because someone didn't know that they needed both an `Ord` instance *and* a rewrite rule to make their type fast. It also doesn't scale at all to higher-kinded types.