# Return `show a` if (Show a) exists, otherwise its type representation if (Typeable a)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I would like to write

```
class Described a where
  describe :: a -> String

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Show a) => Described a where
  describe = show

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Typeable a) => Described a where
  describe = show . typeOf
```

This won't work because the right hand side of each instance is the same. I thought would be solved by having a look at https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap but it seems that I need to define instances for many existing types to make any of these solutions work. What would be the best solution here?

Comment: Define instance for many existing types, IMHO. Or just... don't want this.

Comment: It's possible with Haskell to encode _or_ constraint. Check my answer to another question where I gave an example or how to use function based on whether it has `Ord` or only `Eq` constraint. I think you can do the same for your use case if needed, though I'd still prefer solution with separate `newtype`s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250854/use-specialized-implementation-if-a-class-instance-is-available/44832444#44832444

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use specialized implementation if a class instance is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250854/use-specialized-implementation-if-a-class-instance-is-available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard trick for guiding instance selection is to make a new type. So:

```
newtype DescribeViaTypeable a = DVT a
newtype DescribeViaShow     a = DVS a

instance Show     a => Described (DescribeViaShow     a) where describe (DVS x) = show x
instance Typeable a => Described (DescribeViaTypeable a) where describe (DVT x) = show (typeOf x)
```

Now callers may choose which kind of description they like if both are available, and data types can be explicit about which kind of description they expect to be available for their fields, eliminating any magic.

Comment: My API expects at the minimum some `Typeable` values. But it would be nice to display more information if the value also has a `Show` instance. Having to  manually newtype input values based on their available instances would the API harder to use.

Comment: @Eric In that case, you had better insert and remove the newtype wrappers at your API boundaries, so the user need not see them.

Comment: I could do this but this would require me to provide 2 operation names just with different constraints: `register :: (Typeable a) => a -> Registry as -> Registry (a ': as)` and `registerWhenShow :: (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> Registry as -> Registry (a ': as)`. It feels like the compiler should be able to know which is which

Comment: I also tried this library: https://github.com/mikeizbicki/ifcxt, but I don't get the expected output in GHCi for `ctxShow`.

Comment: @Eric "It feels like the compiler should be able to know which is which" -- your feelings are incorrect. The open-world assumption is a basic premise of the Haskell typeclass system, and says that any code may add an instance for any class/type pair if it wants to -- or, said another way, no code can know a fact of the form "type `T` does not have an instance for class `C`". This makes operations of the form "do X if `T` does not have an instance of `Show`" impossible. `IfCxt` looks clever, but fragile -- I bet I could break it without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I gave all of this more thinking and it makes sense. I realize that I should not try to fight the type system too hard. I eventually changed my API for the better I think