# Problem with creating a type class for a heterogenous operation

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

What follows is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

Suppose I want to create a generic difference operation that can accept operands of different types.

```
class Diff a b c where
    diff :: a -> b -> c
```

Naturally we can apply this operation to numbers.

```
instance Num a ⇒ Diff a a a where
    diff = (-)
```

But not only numbers. If we have say two points in time, then a difference between them would be a time interval.

```
newtype TimePoint = TP Integer deriving Show -- seconds since epoch
newtype TimeInterval = TI Integer deriving Show -- in seconds

instance Diff TimePoint TimePoint TimeInterval where
    diff (Tp x) (Tp y) = TI (x-y)
```

Everything is fine. Except when I try to test my `diff` in GHCi, I get this:

```
*Example λ diff 5 3

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (Diff a0 b0 c)
      from the context: (Diff a b c, Num a, Num b)
        bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
                   forall a b c. (Diff a b c, Num a, Num b) => c
        at <interactive>:1:1-8
      The type variables ‘a0’, ‘b0’ are ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for the inferred type for ‘it’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b c. (Diff a b c, Num a, Num b) => c
*Example λ
```

So I must write type signatures at places where the type should be "obvious" for the compiler.

Let's try to help it a bit.

```
class Diff a b c | a b -> c where
  diff ∷ a -> b -> c
```

It should be able to determine the type of the result now! Unfortunately this doesn't compile:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Example          ( Example.hs, interpreted )

Example.hs:8:10: error:
    Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
      instance Num a => Diff a a a -- Defined at Example.hs:8:10
      instance Num a => Diff (TimePoint a) (TimePoint a) (TimeInterval a)
        -- Defined at Example.hs:14:10
  |
8 | instance Num a => Diff a a a where
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
Prelude GOA λ
```

BTW I have tried associated type families in place of fundeps  as well, with predictably similar results.

Now I understand perfectly well why this happens. There are two instances `Diff a a a` and `Diff (TimePoint a) (TimePoint a) (TimeInterval a)`, and they cannot coexist with the fundep in place. The question is, how do I work around this problem? Wrapping numbers in a newtype is not a viable solution, I need to be able to write `diff 5 3` and `diff time1 time2`, and the types of these expressions should be deduced from the operands.

I know I could define separate instances for `Diff Int Int Int` and `Diff Double Double Double` and `Diff Rational Rational Rational`, but this is not an ideal solution, because new instances of `Num` could be defined and the code must handle them without having to define an additional instance of `Diff` for each of those.

A minimal complete example follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Example where

class Diff a b c | a b -> c where
  diff :: a -> b -> c

instance Num a => Diff a a a where
  diff = (-)

data TimePoint a = TP a deriving Show
data TimeInterval a = TI a deriving Show

instance Num a => Diff (TimePoint a) (TimePoint a) (TimeInterval a) where
  diff (TP x) (TP y) = TI (x - y)
```

Comment: In practice, you should probably just use the [`AffineSpace` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.14/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html).

Comment: Hmm I looked at AffineSpace, it amounts to defining a separate instance for each numeric class.

Comment: And, to reiterate my stance on the dupe: you claim "I need to be able to write `diff 5 3` and `diff time1 time2`", but don't motivate this need. I am skeptical.

Comment: @DanielWagner the so called dupe isn't even close. In my real code, `diff` is called `(-)`. The motivation is to remove a limitation of [numeric-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) explained in the second bullet point of "Scope & Limitations/TODO".

Comment: @n.m. The question asked at the dupe isn't close. But the answer is, namely: you've no choice but to make a bunch of instances or use a newtype wrapper. Read the answers here and you'll see they're identical. And for posterity, the dupe I chose was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52041190/791604). I still don't agree with the folks who voted to reopen: the answers there answer this question, too.

Comment: @DanielWagner I didn't see the answer talking about writing a bunch of instances, only about newtype wrapping (which I understand but cannot use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Diff (TimePoint a) (TimePoint a)` happens to be a special case of `Diff a a`. You may think “it's not because of the `Num a` constraint”, but remember that you can never prove that a type is *not* an instance of some class, because the instance might still be added later.

The solution is to not define a `Diff a a a` instance. Instead define `Diff Int Int Int` and `Diff Double Double Double` and `Diff Rational Rational Rational` separately.

Comment: *define Diff Int Int Int and Diff Double Double Double and Diff Rational Rational Rational separately" I know this will work but this is not ideal because I'm in an environment where new instances of Num are likely to be defined. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: If this is a requirement, then you should better find a solution that doesn't require a custom class at all.

Comment: It isn't a requirement, but it is not desirable. If only I could generate a separate instance of Diff for each instance of Num automatically...

Comment: I'd say just write the one-line instance out for each of these types.

Comment: Well, you _could_ probably hack your way through with overlapping instances instead. I personally stay away from these, but some people use them successfully.

Comment: I have tried overlapping instances too, no luck, The problem is not overlapping but conflicting fundeps (or type families).

Answer (score 1):

You might try a common trick to avoid the head matching problem that @leftaroundabout described in their answer

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (a ~ b, a ~ c, Num a) => Diff a b c where
    diff = (-)
```

This requires `UndecidableInstances`, and `TypeFamilies` to enable the unification constraint, and will not work unless the result of the `diff` is eventually concretely typed, so some level of inference e.g. in GHCi, isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be mostly working, though `diff 5 3` still doesn't work because of overloaded literals. Won't `UndecidableInstances` affect other modules?

Comment: I'm not sure - I've seen it described in a few places (https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick), but it's just a way of manipulating the instance selector.