# Function that behaves differently depending on which type classes the argument belong to

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, is there any way to declare function it behaves differently depending on whether the type of a argument is an instance of specific type class?
For example, can I define `genericShow` in the following example?

```
-- If type `a` is an instance of `Show`.
genericShow :: Show a => a -> String
genericShow = show
-- If type `a` is not an instance of `Show`.
genericShow :: a -> String
genericShow _ = "(Cannot be shown)"

> genericShow 3
"3"
> genericShow const
"(Cannot be shown)"
```

Comment: (1) Closely related: [*Check whether a type is an instance of Show in Haskell?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35785176/2751851); [*Use specialized implementation if a class instance is available*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44250854/2751851). I'm not closing against those now because I'm not sure about which kind of answer would best fit here. (2) In the context of those two questions, [the *constraints-emerge* package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-emerge) is also worth a shout. (3) In any case, as those discussions suggest, this isn't something to be undertaken lightly.

Comment: It helps me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

No.

The closest you can get is to use Overlapping instances, with a catch-all instance for anything not having a more specific `Show` instance.

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Show a  where
  show _ = "(Cannot be shown)"
```

Overlapping instances come with lots of caveats: see topics like 'orphan instances', 'Incoherent instances'. That's particularly awkward with `Prelude` classes like `Show`, because there's likely to be lots of instances hidden away in libraries.

As @duplode says, there are many dangers. Almost certainly there's a better way to achieve whatever it is you think you want.